# multiple file upload and maximum size issues

Tags: php, file-upload, max-size

I have faced the following two problems:
1. The below line from the script isn't checking for maximum file size instead it displays `Please Select a Photo`.

```
//Check that the file is not too big
if ($_FILES[$file_field]['size'] > $max_size) {
    $out['error'][] = "File is too big";
  }
```

2. I would like to let the user upload five photos while one photo is required, meaning the user has the right to upload 1-5 photos but one photo is required, he/she just can't submit the form with all the inputs empty. how can I solve these two issues?

```
<?php

function uploadFile ($file_field = null, $check_image = false, $random_name = false) {

//Config Section    
//Set file upload path
$path = 'Productpic/'; //with trailing slash
//Set max file size in bytes
$max_size = 2097152;
//Set default file extension whitelist
$whitelist_ext = array('jpg','png','gif', 'JPG');
//Set default file type whitelist
$whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png','image/gif');

//The Validation
// Create an array to hold any output
$out = array('error'=>null);

if (!$file_field) {
$out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid form field name";           
}

if (!$path) {
$out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid upload path";               
}

if (count($out['error'])>0) {
return $out;
}

//Make sure that there is a file
if((!empty($_FILES[$file_field])) && ($_FILES[$file_field]['error'] == 0)) {

// Get filename
$file_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$file_field]['name']);
$name = $file_info['filename'];
$ext = $file_info['extension'];

//Check file has the right extension           
if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
  $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Extension";
}

//Check that the file is of the right type
if (!in_array($_FILES[$file_field]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
  $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Type";
}

//Check that the file is not too big
if ($_FILES[$file_field]['size'] > $max_size) {
    $out['error'][] = "File is too big";
  }

//If $check image is set as true
if ($check_image) {
  if (!getimagesize($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'])) {
    $out['error'][] = "The file you trying to upload is not an Image, we only accept images";
  }
}

//Create full filename including path
if ($random_name) {

  // Generate random filename
  $tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

  if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
    $out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
  }     
  $newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                
} else {
    $newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
}

//Check if file already exists on server
if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
  $out['error'][] = "The image you trying to upload already exists, please upload only once";
}

if (count($out['error'])>0) {
  //The file has not correctly validated
  return $out;
} 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
  //Success

  $out['filepath'] = $path;
  $out['filename'] = $newname;
  return $out;
} else {
  $out['error'][] = "Server Error!";
}

} else {
$out['error'][] = "Please select a photo";
return $out;
}      
}
?>



<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$file = uploadFile('file', true, false);
if (!is_array($file['error'])) {
$message = '';
$sub=1;
$message = "File uploaded successfully";
echo $message;
} 

}
?>



<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
if($sub==0)
{
?>
<input name="file" type="file" size="20" /><span><?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$file = uploadFile('file', true, false);
if (is_array($file['error'])) {
$message = '';
foreach ($file['error'] as $msg) {
  $message = $msg;    
}
} 
echo $message;
}
?></span> <br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
<?php
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: have u checked for file upload is on in Apache...

Comment: what you mean by that? I didn't get you.

Comment: in php.ini file search for file_uploads and make it as file_uploads = On

Answer (score 0):

Ensure about the file path. If path is true you can do the job. I recommend you to check file property using exif_imagetype() function it is faster and better than getimage size. In the max file issue you should use filesize() function. Before checking need to ensure that is file is uploaded? The uploaded file is $_FILES('tmp_name').

Comment: actually I tried changing different size of photos and it seems to be working for some of the photos....do you know how to make the script upload multiple photos?